# Where the PHP $_GET superglobal can be used

Tags: php

Can the PHP superglobal $_GET be used and work as intended outside of the form tags? For example, can I do $_GET('select box id') outside of the form tags and have it work as intended?

```
<?php
    ---Placeholder for DB login info---

    switch($_GET['select box id'])
    {
        case "text shown for second option of select box":
        $query = mysql_query("placeholder for actual query");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        $textboxValue = $row[0];
        break;
    }      
?>
```

Comment: off topic: It is strongly recommended to stop using the obsolete `mysql_xx()` functions. You should switch to the `mysqli_xx()` alternatives, or use the PDO library instead.

Comment: Yes. I butchered my question a bit. What I meant to ask is can the $_GET variable be used besides for the purpose of collecting form data?

Comment: Thank you for the mysqli and PDO library advice. I will look into both options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can the PHP superglobal `$_GET` be used and work as intended outside of the form tags?

Yes. The position of PHP code within HTML is entirely irrelevent except in determining where output will appear in a document.

> `$_GET['select box id']`

Form controls use their names for submission keys, not ids.

> `mysql_query`

Read the big red warning box on [the documentation page for that function](http://php.net/mysql_query).

Comment: I butchered my question a bit. What I meant to ask is can the $_GET variable be used besides for the purpose of collecting form data? I'm assuming you mean that the argument $_GET should never be an ID?

Comment: `$_GET` is populated by processing the query string. That query string can be populated using a form or just a link. `$_GET` shouldn't be used for anything else.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide an example on how to populate a query string using a link?

Comment: I'm confused on what this is doing? Can you explain the parts?

Comment: `?` start of query string. `a` key name. `=` end of key, start of value. `b` value.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for login info, you should not be using a get request anyway--you should be using post.

But at any rate, yes it should work. As long as the data is sent with the query, it should work.

That said, you may also want to do some research into some basic security aspects, such as validating and sanitizing inputs. Otherwise, you may wind up opening yourself up to some rather nasty attacks.

I would recommend the book Essential PHP Security from O'Reilly Press. I would also look into using something like MySql PDO for making database queries, as it tends to be more reliable and secure than simply using mysql_query.

Comment: I butchered my question a bit. What I meant to ask is can the $_GET variable be used besides for the purpose of collecting form data? Thanks, I will look into using MySQL PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Superglobal means available for use anywhere/everywhere.